# Time from Terminal B to Terminal A at Newark Airport (EWR), considering immigration procedures

Tags: transit, customs-and-immigration, stopovers, ewr

I will arrive at Terminal B at 12:30 PM via a Lufthansa flight from India after taking a stopover in Munich.And my next flight is from Terminal A at 16:59 to Indianapolis. Considering this is my first time to US, I will have to collect my baggages when I arrive at B, go through immigration, check my luggages back in and then hop on to the Airtrain and reach A. Given the time period, will it be enough for a smooth transit? Just so you know, this will be one single ticket.

Comment: Baggage collection is only after immigration, if I remember correctly at Newark.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, if the transfer time wouldn't be enough to allow the connection to work in most cases, the airline wouldn't sell it to you, as they have to rebook you if you miss your plane if the queue at immigration was too long.

Having said that, more than 4 hours is plenty of time. Commonly, the minimum transfer times from international to domestic are between 90 minutes and 2 hours at US airports, and you are over that by a large margin. Also, as your plane is coming from Munich, there will be many passengers for whom the immigration procedures are relatively fast, which should help to minimize the waiting time.

Comment: But there's no telling how many other planes will have arrived from other parts of the world, carrying passengers for whom immigration procedures will include lengthy interviews.  In my experience, there are usually hundreds of people waiting in line for immigration officers at all times.

Comment: @phoog - Precisely. This is why that part of the answer uses relatively weak statements. It does help that the plane comes from central Europe though. At least the frequent flyers that are likely to deboard earlier than the OP won't cause so much delay on average.

Comment: And travelers to the US from visa waiver program countries can use the [automated passport control](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/automated-passport-control-apc) kiosks, if this is not their first visit, which would further reduce queues if more of them knew it!